# Codepipeline: Insufficient permissions Unable to access the artifact with Amazon S3 object key located in amazon s3 artifact bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, terraform, aws-codepipeline

Unable to access the artifact with Amazon S3 object key 'Warehouse-WebApplica/build_outp/PhntxUV' located in the Amazon S3 artifact bucket 'cicd-***************.codepipeline-artifacts.eu-east-1'. The provided role does not have sufficient permissions.

Hello I created a codepipeline project with the following configuration:

Source Code in S3 pulled from Bitbucket.
Build with CodeBuild, generating an docker image and storing it into a Amazon ECR repository.
Deployment provider Amazon ECS.
All the process works ok until when it tries to deploy, for some reason I am getting the following error during deployment:

Unable to access the artifact with Amazon S3 object key 'Warehouse-WebApplica/build_outp/PhntxUV' located in the Amazon S3 artifact bucket 'cicd-******.codepipeline-artifacts.eu-east-1'. The provided role does not have sufficient permissions.

Comment: Can you check and display the CodedBuild Role IAM permissions ? How is build your pipeline and which step is failing ?